# Why my webkit could't find libflashplayer.so under the directory of /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins

Tags: c, linux, flash, webkit, webkitgtk

I am developing an application for GTk+3.0 and webkitGTK+ of linux, that's supposed to play swf files inside a WebView. First I tried to open the swf file from the device, than through the internet, with no luck. The WebView shows up, but inside the WebView all I can see is a white screen(Missing plug-in). If I load the same URL to the device browser, the flash file plays well. And I got libflashplayer.so and install

sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins

I think Im missing something on the WebView setup, but after a few hours of searching and googling I still dont know what.

Comment: Check the permissions on the newly copied `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so` - it may have been copied in such a way non-root users cannot access it.

Comment: I changed to root user and cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so  again.  But it still not work. My God!!!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, the Flash plugin should be detected and loaded fine if installed into `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`. (WebKit does not look in `/opt/google/chrome/plugins` so putting it there has no effect.)

At the time you posted this question, WebKitGTK+ was unable to handle Flash because Flash is linked to GTK+ 2, while your application was using GTK+ 3. It's impossible to mix both versions of GTK+ in the same application; attempting to load the Flash plugin would have caused your application to hang, so WebKit skipped the plugin. So the problem was that *Adobe Flash is incompatible with GTK+ 3*.

Nowadays, WebKitGTK+ runs plugins in a separate plugin process, so this is no longer an issue. It has two separate plugin processes, one linked against GTK+ 3, and one linked against GTK+ 2, and selects the right plugin process to use for the plugin at runtime.